# How to use cocoapods in xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nuget, cocoapods

I would like to make use of couple of cocoapods in my xamarin.ios project.
But I couldn't find those cocoapods in Nuget which is package manager for Xamarin.

I heard we can compile a xcode project into a static library ... that is .a file and use it in xamarin.

But I am getting confused on how to convert the pods into a static library or something so that I can use those pods in my xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take the Pod directly and create a static library but you can although create a static library from the Pod project which already contains your pod. But to be honest the best solution will be getting the source code of the project and create the static library from there. Most of the Pods out there are open source so grabbing the source code from github should not be a problem.

Once you have the source code follow [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial) example to show you how to create static libraries from there.

Once you have created the static library you just need to follow [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries/) tutorial to create a Binding library that can be used in Xamarin.

Unfortunately AFAK there's not support yet for Swift libraries to create binding libraries so this will only work with objective-c code.

Comment: Are you sure its possible to do this way ?

Comment: if we don't have source code then how to proceed ? because basically there are so many pods I have to use ... not sure .. if alll will have source code out there

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure you can create a Static Library from a pod project, what I cannot assure is that using this library you will be able to create the binding library, this is because I haven't tried. I mentioned it as a option you could try but definitely using the source code is the best option.

Comment: @Shiva check this link: http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/automatic-build-of-static-library-for-ios-for-many-architectures/

Comment: Static library and binding library are two different things or the same ?

Comment: They are different. Static library (in this case) is an ios/xcode concept. Basically you take an Objective-C static library and convert it to a Binding library. Binding libraries (Xamarin) can then be used in a Xamarin project.

Comment: Binding libraries can then be used like just anyother library in xamarin ... Am I right ? so can we convert the static library to binding library using xamarin studio ?

Comment: Yes.. The link above shows you how to do it using Xamarin Studio. Here's again: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries/

Comment: @apineda - Swift project can be converted to Cocoa touch framework so can cocoa touch framework be used for Binding to Xamarin ?

Comment: You can use Sharpie to bring the cocoapods into your project and also bind them - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/cocoapod/